# Where does Dispatcher get control from?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-controls

In a user-control, I have a thread besides main thread to process data, then show result in a text box like this

```
private delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
private void SetText(string text)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), text);
        return;
    }
    txtResult.Text = text;
}

private void ProcessThread()
{
    string result = "";
    // process ...
    SetText(result);
}
```

On the first application run, this user-control worked perfectly. If I close and open it again, it's not working. Then I debug into SetText function, the txtResult.Text show that value has been assigned but it's empty on the UI. I tried with other controls like enabling a button but the result is the same: in debug, controls had held new value but not on UI. I got a feeling that this thread got controls from closed user-control.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong ? Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english.

**UPDATE**

My thread initilization:

```
private Timer _timer;
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _timer = new Timer(ProcessThread);
}
```

Where I call my thread

```
private void _OnSomeCustomEvent(object sender)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        _timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're asking where SetText() gets txtResult from?

Comment: Yes, i think so. Can you help me ?

Comment: From what I found in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx#threading_overview) _"At construction, a DispatcherObject stores a reference to the Dispatcher linked to the currently running thread."_ Is this mean that each thread created an instance of dispatcher ?

Comment: It's getting it from somewhere in your code. Can you share that part? It sounds like the second time you run your code￼, it has a stale reference to the UI left over from the first time you ran your code. But I can't say how or why without seeing the code.

Comment: When you say "close and open it again" do you really mean restarting the application? Or just a window or something? Our need to provide enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Obviously, you store references to the first created control somewhere, so your code still tries to change the things that are not visible anymore. It's one more reason no to use the code-behind but do the things in a MVVM way.

Comment: @EdPlunkett it's just a windows on the application. If I close the application, then reopen, this windows will work. But if I just close this windows, not the app, then this windows is not working.

Comment: @dymanoid can you tell me how to work around this issue ? That would be a great help

Comment: Again, you need to provide enough code to reproduce the issue. I have asked you twice already. This is my last attempt.

Comment: it's not that I don't want to upload my code, it's just too big and requires other custom libraries, database, devices to run properly. If possible, can you add my skype so that I can show you. My skype nguyen_duy92

Comment: @user1728585 I just needed to see enough to re-create the issue. I didn't need your libraries and databases. But as I said, that was my last attempt.

Comment: One last note (which you'll also ignore): Your *fundamental* problem here is that you didn't use MVVM. Throw away all the UI code you have and use MVVM. That'll fix this issue and a lot of other issues you haven't run into yet.

Answer (score 0):

Move txtResult.Text = text; inside dispatcher invoke

Dispatcher should be used to access UI controls from a background thread

This should work

Comment: you mean something like this: `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { txtResult.Text = text; }));` ?